# Removing an element from array without any built-in function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

The question is:
"Write and test the following function that removes items from an array:

```
void removeAll(float a[], int& n, float x);
```

The function removes all occurrences of x among the first n elements of the array and decreases the value of n by the number removed.

I have written a code and it works perfectly fine. Basically, I tagged the value whose occurrences the user wants to remove with Zero and the code skips printing when it encounters zero. Basically we are not removing that value from the array just replacing it with some other value. What if the user entered zero in the array? then the other zeroes will also be skipped which I don't want them too. how can I do this?

Here is my code:

Don't use any classes, objects, vectors, strings nor any function in c++ which is like array.splice in js.

```
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;


void removeAll(float a[], int &n, float x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == x)
        {
            a[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (a[i]!=0)
            cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    float a[10], x;
    int n;
    cout << "Enter values in array: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    cout << "Enter the value whose occurrence you want to remove from the array: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter serial no. uptill which you want to remove the occurences";
    cin >> n;
    removeAll(a, n, x);
}
```

Comment: Technically you can't *remove* an element of an array. An array will always have a fixed size and a fixed number of elements.

Comment: There you are not really removing the element of the array, but more removing it from the final displaying.

Comment: Aside from that, there's no need to pass `n` by reference to your function.

Comment: I know! that's what the teacher and the question says.

Comment: Don't try to trick the callers of the code, they'll see quite easily all you did was "make a hole in the array". Instead of trying to be overly clever, find the element, and then copy all the remaining elements one place to the left.

Comment: I can't go against the question bro.

Comment: Lastly, what is the *problem* with the code you show? What is your *question*? Do your code do what it is supposed to do? Is the output what you expect it to be? Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: the teacher said he wants a "hole in the array" thingy. i know we cant technically remove values from arrays

Comment: You ARE going against the question. the question says: "that removes items from an array", you are NOT removing items from the array.

Comment: Either the teacher is wrong (inconsistent with the question), or you have misunderstood either the question or the teacher.

Comment: "it metaphorically says remove"  as quoted by my teacher when i asked the same thing

Comment: Then change teacher, you are going no way good with this one :-/

Comment: @noorahmad - "metaphorically" doesn't mean "make a hole", it means "despite the buffer not changing size, it will have only n - 1 elements officially"

Comment: I guess i'm going to deans office tomorrow with a complaint. RIP my teacher

Comment: Consider using some kind of *linked list* - it's quite good for making holes in it)

Comment: Anyway thank you all for answering so quickly! :)

Comment: This "hole in the array" thing sounds fishy to me. For me removing e.g. 0 from this array of size 6 `1,2,0,5,0,6` should result in this array of size 4: `1,2,5,6`, at least that is how I understand the question.

Comment: What your teacher is asking you to do is write a function that does what [`std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) in conjunction with `erase` does (erase remove idiom).

Comment: let's say the values in my array is {1,2,1,2,3,4,5,1,3} i say i wanna remove 1 occurences uptill the 3rd value i.e untill after the first 2. so i make the array {0,2,0,2,3,4,5,1,3} then skip the printing of zeroes. but what if there were other zeroes as well in that array. it would skip those zeroes as well

Comment: sorry nathan that's not allowed nor taught to us but thanks!

Comment: @noorahmad I know it is not allowed but that is the functionality they want you to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to print out the array without a chosen variable you can do it with one condition:

```
void removeAll(float a[], int &n, float x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == x)
        {
            // Don't print it
        }
        else
        {
            cout << a[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to eliminate the occurrences I would suggest to move the following numbers forward. I won't code it but here is an example:

```
array: 2,3,4,5,3,7
number to remove: 3

1. Iterate through the array and find '3'
2. If you find one, move all elements on the right side on step to left:
   2 3 4 5 3 7  => 2 4 5 3 7 X
     ^
   2 4 5 3 7 X  => 2 4 5 7 X X
         ^
3. Count how many times you have done step two and return the new length/new array
```

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this you'll need to do 4 things:

1. Make a copy of `n` to hold the number of elements to iterate over: `int size = n`
2. Change your loop condition to consider this new element rather than `n`: `i < size`
3. Decrement `n` each time you replace a value in the nested `if`-statement
4. Remove the second `for`-loop (if you want to print out everything under `n` but the replaced numbers do that in an `else`-condition.)